# Missing IN or OUT parameter oracle database on groovy

Tags: oracle, groovy, plsql

I'm trying to create a trigger after a table has been created on a Oracle XE 11g database but I'm getting a missing parameter error.

```
        sql.execute("CREATE TABLE flows (id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,name VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,package VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,content VARCHAR2(4000),status VARCHAR2(50),nextRun NUMBER)")
        sql.execute('CREATE SEQUENCE id_seq')
        sql.call("""
                    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER id_trig
                    BEFORE INSERT ON FLOWS
                    FOR EACH ROW
                    BEGIN
                      SELECT id_seq.nextval into :new.id FROM dual;
                    END;
                """)
```

Logs:

```
Oct 11, 2016 10:40:45 AM groovy.sql.Sql call
WARNING: Failed to execute: 
                    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER id_trig
                    BEFORE INSERT ON FLOWS
                    FOR EACH ROW
                    BEGIN
                      SELECT id_seq.nextval into :new.id FROM dual;
                    END;
                     because: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1
```

Comment: I don't know Groovy, but it looks like your tool is trying to pass a bind variable at `:new.id`. You will need to look up how to escape that, or otherwise signal to the engine that you don't intend to bind anything.

Comment: It seems that you are right. Groovy doesn't provide a documentation how to escape that. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

`sql.call` is trying to call procedure. You're going to create trigger so I think you should also use `sql.execute`

```
sql.execute("
                    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER id_trig
                    BEFORE INSERT ON FLOWS
                    FOR EACH ROW
                    BEGIN
                      SELECT id_seq.nextval into :new.id FROM dual;
                    END;
                ")
```